# Finding Total of ArrayList Objects Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, playing-cards

I need to find the total of some ArrayList objects (playing card values). I have a Card.java class and a User.java class. I have a userHand ArrayList also. I'm not getting any errors but it's not printing the sum. Here is my code:

**Card.java**

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Card {

//Variables
public static String[] card_types = { "spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds"};
public static int value;
public static String type;

Card(){
    value = genCardValue();
    type = genCardType();
}

//Get the value of the card
public static int getValue(){
    return value;
}

//Get the type of the card
public static String getType(){
    return type;
}

//Generate the card value (example: 5)
public static int genCardValue(){

    int min = 2;
    int max = 11;
    int range = max - min;

    int cardValue = new Random().nextInt(range + 1) + 2;

    return cardValue;
}


//Generate the card type (example: spades)
public static String genCardType(){
    String cardType = (card_types[new Random().nextInt(card_types.length)]);

    return cardType;
}


}
```

**User.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

List<Card> userHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
int i = 10;

User(){
    userHand.add(0, new Card());
    userHand.add(1, new Card());
    int sum = 0;

    for (Card card : userHand){
        int cardValue = card.getValue();
        sum += cardValue;
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}


}
```

It is just printing blank. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What results ware you expecting and why?

Comment: This is not a runnable program - can you post something with a main method please?

Comment: If you take a look at the Card.java class it will generate a random number. Then set value to it. The method getValue() would then return the value which I called in the for loop in the User.java class.

Comment: can you explain these two lines?  userHand.add(0, new Card());
    userHand.add(1, new Card()); **I do not see any constructor to produce such objects so you can add them to your arraryList**

Comment: @user1886323 Currently I'm just testing. I have a main method but it doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: @KickButtowski Take a look at the Card.java class. There is a Card constructor.

Comment: When I call `new User()` I see as result values like `4` `20` `22` which seems fine to me. Please provide code which will let us reproduce actual problem.

Comment: Where did you call `new User()`? Those are perfect results but I'm not getting them...

Comment: If you don't have anything in your main method then how are you running this code?

Comment: @fleebow8 I do not get it the only constructor that I see is Card() and there is no argument insdie it

Comment: In main method of some class like `public class Demo { public static void main(String[] args) { new User(); } }`, but what is important is that ` new User();` is only code there so it isn't affected by anything else.

Comment: Oh wow I actually did get those results when I restarted my IDE... I think it was an IDE bug because I tried running my other programs and they wouldn't print either. Whoops! Sorry for troubling you guys :D

Comment: Yep it worked for me @Pshemo Thanks for you help!

Comment: Take a look at posted answer. It is very good advice since `type` and `value` should belong to instance, not entire class.

Comment: @Pshemo but it is not related to the issue that op asked ? is it?

Comment: True... I'll do that.

Comment: @Pshemo can you answer my comment if you donot mind? "I do not get it the only constructor that I see is Card() and there is no argument insdie it"

Comment: @KickButtowski True, but it still is useful information.

Comment: @KickButtowski If your comment was about `userHand.add(0, new Card());` then I don't see any problem with it. We are calling `add` method on a list which sets at position `0` new instance of `Card` by using `Card(){
  value = genCardValue();
  type = genCardType();
 }` constructor.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for your answer but It is kind of odd way of using constructor to me

Comment: @KickButtowski If we want to have few objects but we don't want to have many references to them, we can create them and immediately pass to some collection (or array). It is similar as using `Person[] people = {new Person("Adam"), new Foo("Eve")}` or `List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(new Person("Adam"), new Foo("Eve"));`.

Comment: @Pshemo wowww learn something new . is there any keyword so I can read about this way more?

Comment: @KickButtowski What may be new information which not many people notice at first is in code like `Foo foo = new Foo()` it is `new` keyword which is responsible for creation and returning of created `Foo` object. That is why we are able to store this object in `foo` reference. So in `new Foo()` we are doing 3 things: (1) new creates empty object of type Foo, (2) then constructor code is being called to properly set-up (initialize) this new object (notice that in constructor we are able to use `this` keyword to refer to that uninitialized object) (3) `new` returns now initialized object.

Comment: @KickButtowski How we will handle object returned by `new` is up to us. Most often we will assign it to new reference like `Foo foo =`, but we don't need to create new reference all the time. We can also use already existing one, or even reference representing method parameter like `method(Foo foo)` and call `method(new Foo())`. We can also not assign this object anywhere like I did in my `Demo` class and let it be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `static` from your code (It's just an advice how to do it right). And run code from `main` method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        new User();
    }
```

Also you can simplify this:

```
userHand.add(0, new Card());
userHand.add(1, new Card());
```

to just:

```
userHand.add(new Card());
userHand.add(new Card());
```

Also it's better to move sum logic from constructor to separate method:

```
  public int sum() {
        int res = 0;
        for (Card card : userHand) {
            int cardValue = card.getValue();
            res += cardValue;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

And call it when you want to see the sum:

```
User u = new User();
System.out.println(user.sum());
```

Comment: how this is an answer?

Comment: I did move the sum logic to it's own method. Being in the constructor was just for testing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `static` type from all the `instance variables` and methods in the `Card` class.
`static` defines something which is bound my class, one per class. Therefore, all the instances of that class all share that `static instance variable`.

I would also re-organize your code to the following:

```
int sum;

User(){
    userHand.add(new Card());
    userHand.add(new Card());
    iterate();
}

void inerate(){
 for (Card card : userHand){
        int cardValue = card.getValue();
        sum += cardValue;
    }
}

int getSum(){
   return sum;
}
```

You should also create an instance of type User to start the method call procedure:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    User user = new User();
    System.out.println(user.getSum());
}
```

Comment: your answer does not help or answer what the op is looking for